# Navigaton bar not toggling in small devices

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, uinavigationcontroller

I have written the following code for the navigation bar but when I open the code in a small device then the hamburger icon is not working it is there but nothing is happening when I try to click it

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">
        <img src="../../../assets/img.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Trouvaille Social Network
    </a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <!-- if the user is present then printing email -->
            <li>
                <div *ngIf="email" class="navbar-text float-left">
                    {{email}}
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a [routerLink]=" ['/'] " class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a *ngIf="!email" [routerLink]=" ['/signin'] " routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item nav-link">Sign
                    In</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a *ngIf="!email" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]=" ['/signup'] " class="nav-item nav-link">Sign
                    Up</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a *ngIf="email" (click)="handleSignOut()" class="nav-item nav-link text-warning">Log Out</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a *ngIf="email" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]=" ['/addpost']"
                    class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-warning text-primary">
                    Post Your Story</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

this is my code on small devices hamburger icon is appearing but nothing is happening on clicking it

Comment: read 'How it works' section of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/ please

Comment: didn't get anything after reading

Comment: It says ' Responsive behavior depends on our Collapse JavaScript plugin ', Basically it is not working because probably you don't have JQuery & Bootstrap js with your angular. Bringing JQuery to angular is very bad, Angular won't get to know the manipulations jquery makes to Dom. There should be only one framework manipulating the Dom. So what you can do there manually hood the event window resize and with a hostlistner and the adjust the html part accordingly. Or if wanted to go simple use ngxbootstrap or something similar and follow their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the bootstrap.js or you have incorrectly loaded it in the `<head>` it should be just before the closing body tag.

Refer to the starter template https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Put content here -->


    <!-- End of content -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```